# Silent authentication of a webview that opens a Sharepoint url

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal, expo-auth-session

We have a React Native application that authenticates with Azure AD via an in-app-browser (using https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/). In another part of the app, we have to display a blog post from Sharepoint in a webview. However, Sharepoint requires the user to log in, which leads to a poor user experience.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to silent-authenticate the webview by acquiring the necessary cookies with the access token we already have from the in-app-browser authentication and then setting them on the webview.
*I have found that the rtFA and FedAuth cookies are important.*

Opening Sharepoint in an In-App-Browser would also be fine.

Any other solutions to this problem are also welcome.